# How to handle Interstitial onAdListener if activity it was loaded is not current activity Android admob?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I have created an application on click of button i check if Interestial its loaded if yes i show it. But this is most of time not loaded.

I load interstitial ad in onCreate of that activity as follows:

```
     interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And on click of button i download some stuff after which i show ad with following code:

```
if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitial.show();
                }
```

But ad is never shown how to handle this?

Please help

Comment: Can you show your whole class? I guess you did not implement the listener correctly

Comment: @Michael i have not implemented listener i dont how its going to work.. Need help on how it works and how much time ad takes normally

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/interstitial/src/com/google/example/gms/ads/advanced/InterstitialSample.java)

especially:

```
// Set the AdListener.
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() { ...
```

If you carefully read this, loading an interstitial shouldnt be a problem! And for your question, you cannot say an interstitial needs x seconds to load, therefor you need the listener, which gets called, when the interstitial loaded or failed to load

Comment: so if i add listener for interstitialAd in ActivityA and load in its onCreate and say i leave ActivityA and go to ActivityB will it still listen?

Comment: yes it will. But if the user is on the next screen already, you should not show him the interstitial. I am not sure, if everything works correctly, when the user switched to a new activity

Comment: okay so i will put listener and irrespective of activity it was loaded it will listen and show it when its loaded right?

Comment: you can do that yes. Play around a little bit with the listener. Check behaviour if you go to the next activity immediately

Comment: If listener works independent of which activity it was loaded from then fine else need another way to handle it

Comment: i tried but getting following info in logcat:

11-04 09:32:02.046: I/Ads(29747): No fill from ad server.
11-04 09:32:02.066: W/Ads(29747): Failed to load ad: 3

What does this mean

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not receiving any ad to show.
I suggest you use mediation to forward the ad request to other ad networks if your first choice fails.
See https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3124703?hl=en